# How to change favicon of moodle?

Tags: docker, moodle, favicon

I'm running moodle using docker and I'm trying to change the favicon of the site. Does anyone knows an answer for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In most, but not all, Moodle 2.x.x themes have custom settings pages, which you will find in the links listed under Settings > Site Administration > Appearance > Themes > ... Listed at this point you will see a list of Theme names, including Formal White. If you CLICK this link you will find the Custom Settings page associated with this theme. It is in this settings page that you can add your logo. All the instructions on how to do this are on that page.

I hope this helps in the Moodle maze or theme development.

Comment: I tried it. Its not working. Do you know about using moodle with docker? A big help if you know